# How do I debug an Apache web server failing to load on windows?

Tags: apache-http-server, php, logging

On my dev environment I upgraded php with an msi, and my apache wouldn't load anymore[image: error message].

Where can I find information about the reason it failed? 
I have the error logs for each virtual server, but no information there either, and I am not sure that I actually expect it to be found there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Starting Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/invoking.html) says

> If Apache suffers a fatal problem during startup, it will write a message describing the problem either to the console or to the ErrorLog before exiting.

I would try [Running Apache as a console application](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/platform/windows.html#wincons) expecting to see console error messages saying that it can't parse the config file (and hence doesn't know where it's errorlogs are to be written) - it should give some reasons that will be helpful

I'd also try `httpd.exe -k configtest` in a command prompt window (I've no idea if this will work)

You may need to tell Apache where the main config file is by using the `-f` option e.g. `-f "c:\my server files\anotherconfig.conf"`

Comment: I don't seem to have httpd.exe anywhere in my apache folder

Comment: At the meanwhile I found the reason by trial and error. But will follow your guidence later, to learn for future. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Goto the Apache installation directory and look for logs/errors.log in some older apache versions the startup log should be enabled. Sometimes apache writes in to the application log in windows event viewer

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that under :

> compmgmt.msc > Event Viewer > Windows Logs > Application

You can easily see what logs are generated to Windows, like

> tail -f /etc/syslog

on Linux systems.